# Code is not working for swing image button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

i have written this code for showing image instead of button following
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898584/java-using-an-image-as-a-button)

My code is:

```
JButton btnCalender;
    try {
        
        BufferedImage calendarIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("Calendar_0.jpg"));
        btnCalender = new JButton("Calendar", new ImageIcon(calendarIcon));
        btnCalender.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        btnCalender.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnCalender.setBounds(244, 177, 129, 36);
        frmOptions.getContentPane().add(btnCalender);
        btnCalender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But image is not showing. The button area is blank. All images are in Project folder.
Why This is happening? Please give me solution. Thanks.

**Edit:
Solution found.
My image resulation was too big. I've compressed this into 144*144.
Now it is working.**

Comment: It doesn't get problem for me.

Comment: Do you run it from any IDE? Why you keep images at source folder?

Comment: Yes. all images are in src folder. I've put this images in project folder too. But not working. IDE eclipes with windowbuilder.

Comment: Looks like an incorrect path. For debugging porpuses try to set the path image absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted looks fine.  Without the rest of the code it is hard to tell for sure, but it appears that the issue you are having is related to actually putting the button on the GUI.

Double-check that aren't getting any IOExceptions finding/loading the image.

Comment: There is no I/O exception. I've checked this. Images are in Project folder also. But still now no result.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE because there is something else going on that you aren't including then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
btnCalender.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try **removing border  and content** area like this:

```
BufferedImage calendarIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("Calendar_0.jpg"));
btnCalender = new JButton("Back", new ImageIcon(calendarIcon));
btnCalender.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
btnCalender.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: i have tried this code and it's working for me, please check the image exists and is in the rigth directory

Answer (score 0):

There is two things you can try, firstly make sure you have specified the layout "exact positioning" for the contentPane 
`frmOptions.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` 
and also make sure you repaint your contentPane after you've added the jbutton component like this
`frmOptions.getContentPane().repaint();`
Remember to put it AFTER you have added your button to the contentPane!

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("This is a test");
    f.setSize(400, 150);
    Container content = f.getContentPane();
    BufferedImage calendarIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\sugandhan\\Desktop\\suganthan.jpg"));
    content.add(new JButton("Calendar", new ImageIcon(calendarIcon)));
    f.setVisible(true);
```

And Please check you image path

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need a bufferedImage to do this, secondly you have to correct the link of the image like this :

JFrame frmOptions = new JFrame();

```
JButton btnCalender = new JButton("Calendar", new ImageIcon(
        "./src/Calendar_0.jpg"));
btnCalender.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
btnCalender.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btnCalender.setBounds(244, 177, 129, 36);

btnCalender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
});
frmOptions.getContentPane().add(btnCalender);
frmOptions.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
frmOptions.pack();
frmOptions.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frmOptions.setVisible(true);
```

I hope that helps, if so make it up please ;) Salam