# How to make button like music player using java.swing

Tags: java, swing, button

Now I create gui music player with java. In java.swing.JButton, there are square buttons , but I want to customize that button like music player's button. How to make buttons like 'Play Button' in music player? And I also want stop and reset buttons, too.

play button is like ▶ this shape in circle.
stop button is like || this shape in circle.
reset button is like ■ this shape in circle.

thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the play like image to the JButton.

Save your image named "playname" to "path/to/image/" and call as shown in this code:

```
// JButton play = new JButton();
// assuming play is the place where you've added your JButton
ImageIcon playimg = new ImageIcon("path/to/image/playname");
play.setIcon(playimg);
```

You can similarly add the same logic for other buttons too.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set the text of the JButton as the symbol ▶

```
JButton button = new JButton("▶");
```

You need to save the .java file with UTF-8 character set though, in eclipse it's really easy as you get a popup.

It's the easiest but least customizable solution.
Another workaround would be to create an image with whatever symbol you wish the button to show. Then add a [rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) to the image's bounds. To check for mouse clicks, simply use a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and do something similar to this:

```
if(mouse.isClicked() && rect.contains(mouse.x, mouse.y) { //do stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the button have an image in i, or make the image a button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the immage you want to the Button. This way you can have a button with Play Icon!

Example:

```
JButton button= new JButton();
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("imgfolder/name.png");
button.setIcon(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make custom button, there is only one easy way to do it. First way is find a custom button library or [make your button from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898584/java-using-an-image-as-a-button).

Else you can try [look on this another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158/creating-a-custom-button-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using rendered images (like a PNG) and an `ImageIcon`, you could use [Java2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) Shapes/Areas.

E.g. to create a *Play* [Area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html), do something like this:

```
final GeneralPath play = new GeneralPath();
play.moveTo(1.0/5.0, 1.0/5.0);
play.lineTo(1.0/5.0, 1.0*4.0/5.0);
play.lineTo(1.0*4.0/5.0, 1.0/2.0);
play.closePath();
final Area playArea = new Area(play);
```

To draw the shape as `Icon`, use this custom class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class ShapeIcon implements Icon {

    private final Shape shape;
    private final Paint paint;
    private final Color color;
    private final int size;
    private final boolean fill;
    private final Stroke stroke;

    public ShapeIcon(final Shape shape, final Color color, final int size) {
        this(shape, color, size, true, new BasicStroke(0.5f));
    }

    public ShapeIcon(final Shape shape, final Color color, final int size, final boolean fill, final Stroke stroke) {
        this.stroke = stroke;
        this.fill = fill;
        this.color = color;
        // allow for customization of fill color/gradient
        // a plain color works just as well—this is a little fancier
        this.paint = new GradientPaint(0, 12, color.brighter(), 0, 20, color);
        this.size = size;
        // you could also define different constructors for different Shapes
        if (shape instanceof Path2D) {
            this.shape = ((Path2D)shape).createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(size, size));
        } else if (shape instanceof Area) {
            this.shape = ((Area) shape).createTransformedArea(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(size, size));
        } else {
            this.shape = new Area(shape).createTransformedArea(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(size, size));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y) {
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.translate(x, y);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        if (fill) {
            g2d.setPaint(paint);
            g2d.fill(shape);
        }
        g2d.setPaint(color);
        g2d.setStroke(stroke);
        g2d.draw(shape);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the setBorder method of JButton.

```
roundButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));
```